# Java - generic parameter can't be resolved

Tags: java, generics

I'm writing a generic Dao interface and I have encountered some problems.

I have the following generic Entity interface

```
public interface Entity<T> {

    T getId();

    //more code
}
```

So the generic parameter is supposed to represent the id of the entity.
And now I want to write a generic Dao initerface like this

```
public interface Dao<T extends Entity<E>> {

    //more code

    T find(E id); 

}
```

To be able to call

```
T find(E id)
```

Instead of having to call

```
T find(Object id)
```

which isn't typesafe.

Unfortunately the compiler doesn't seem to be able to resolve the E in

```
Dao<T extends Entity<E>>
```

Do any of you know if there is a workaround to this problem, or is it just impossible to do in Java?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to pass the primary key as parameter too:

```java
public interface Dao<K, T extends Entity<K>>
```

The pk usually is serializable, so you can improve the above signature:

```java
public interface Dao<K extends Serializable, T extends Entity<K>>
```

And:

```java
public interface Entity<K extends Serializable>
```

Then:

```java
public class UserDao implements Dao<Integer, User> {
}
```

Comment: Ick! `Serializable` :( There are soooo many serialization frameworks putting it to shame that I don't ever see that interface implemented by anyone except for backwards compatibility...

Comment: @fge Never heard about that point... Do you have some docs/articles?

Comment: @sp00m JSON, protobuf, XML blah blah... Pick your poison. (well, OK, no XML for me) I fail to see any valid reason to use `Serializable` in a Java project started in the 21st century.